# What is the best way to pass data from one activity to another without starting it?

Tags: java, android

Let's say that I have an Edit Text in Activity 1 and I want to pass what's written to Activity 2 without opening the Activity 2 when I click on Save button for example. Then when I go to Activity 2 I need to retrieve what I have already saved . I thought about using Shared Preferences but I'm afraid it's limited and also because later all data in Activity 2 must be stored in a database. What's the best way to pass data in such cases?

Comment: Since you are going to use a database anyways, what's wrong with storing that activity 1 value in there? Then on Activity 2 just retrieve the db value

Comment: You are right but I'm afraid this will increase the interaction between the user and the database because as you know Firebase databases charge you according to the number of reads . I'm not totally sure but what you said seems the best way.

Comment: Then just use sqlite/room to store those kind of values that are not necessary changing on the short term. Just check if there is or isn't stored values there in order to call firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value using like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME,name);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL,email);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and can access in next activity using below

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        textUserName.setText(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_USERNAME));
        textEmail.setText(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_EMAIL));
```

Comment: Yeah but this code will start the next activity which is something I don't want to do.